# Memory Leak issue org.apache.tomcat.util.collections.SynchronizedStack class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

We did a load test on our spring boot file download application by putting a load of 4000 concurrent users Out of which 3995 succeeded and 5 of them failed.

The file which we download is of `1 MB` per request.

We took a heap dump at the end of the load test using

`jcmd pid GC.heap_dump <filename>`

After analyzing the heap dump I realised that the tomcat's org.apache.tomcat.util.collections.SynchronizedStack<org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel> are not being released. We had tested with multiple load of users from 500, 700 & 4000. This particular object keeps increasing in memory but does not release any.

This is my tomcat config in application.properties

```
server.tomcat.connection-timeout=20s
server.tomcat.accept-count=5000
server.tomcat.max-connections=50000
server.tomcat.max-threads=10000
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Am I missing anything in my tomcat configuration for spring boot?

Application stack: spring boot 2.2.0.RELEASE on Open JDK 11.

Some code which we have used for the file download:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/file/download/{downloadToken}")
@ApiOperation(value = "downloadFile", authorizations = {@Authorization(value = "apiKey")})
public StreamingResponseBody downloadFile(@PathVariable String downloadToken,
    HttpServletResponse response) {
    MyFileObject myFileObject = myFileService.downloadFile(downloadToken);
    response.setContentType(myFileObject.getContentType());
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
        "attachment; filename=\"" + myFileObject.getFileName() + "\"");
    return out -> {
        try (OutputStream os = out) {
            os.write(myFileObject.getData());
        }
    };
}
```

The MyFileObject which is the DTO

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
class MyFileObject {
    private String fileName;
    private String contentType;
    private byte[] data;
}
```

Note: We have the entire byte[] data (1 MB) in memory due to other business reasons. However, as per heap dump this is not the cause of the leak as these objects are GCed.

Some screenshots from MAT tool of the heap dump

[image: Heap summary]
[image]

Comment: Remove the `try`. YOu don't control the `OutputStream` the servlet container does that. Also do you really need that many threads and possible connections? Each thread and connection takes up memory and will stay in memory.

Comment: Since the data written is a byte[] of 1 MB and the client connections could be slower we did not want too many connections to wait for the slower ones to complete therefore had increased the thread count. Also, you mentioned that each thread and connection will remain in memory. But the connection should close after some time and release the memory. Thread can remain.

Comment: The only way to have `SynchronizdStack` use less memory is by reducing the ``. According to the documentation of [`SynchronizdStack`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/collections/SynchronizedStack.html): "..when the requirement is to create a pool of re-usable objects **with no requirement to shrink the pool**.." you cannot configure the `SynchronizedStack` to shrink the pool

Comment: @ThomasKläger I think you meant by reducing the `threads`. We are ok for those threads to occupy the heap space but do you think that the connections should close after some time? I did not see that happening after doing heap dumps even after 1 hour.